# Вывести сумму значений столбца

Tags: php

Вопрос такой - 
Как вывести значение выборки ?+)

```
$summa = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(amusd) FROM tabl WHERE status!=0 AND id=$id")or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: @RattleSneyk - у вас был вопрос по поводу двух ключей и вставки. Используйте конструкцию `INSERT INTO table (a,b,c) VALUES (1,2,3) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE c=c+1;`


[Пруф][1]

[1]: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У элементов выборки могут быть псевдонимы.

```
SELECT SUM(amusd) as sum_amusd FROM tabl WHERE status!=0 AND id=$id
```

Обращайтесь как к столбцу `sum_amusd` (псевдоним `sum_amusd` взят для примера, тут может быть любая строка.)

P.S.: cлово `as` можно опускать.